# Autoresponders function with e-mail headers that display a name rathe than e-mail

Tags: php, email, header, auto

I got this code. But since trying including the header, I'm longer receiving the email. I got PHP version 7.4

```php
#hook in to wpcf7_mail_sent - this will happen after form is submitted
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' ); 

#our autoresponders function
function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {

    if( $contact_form->id==14383 ){

        #retrieve the details of the form/post
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
  
        $headers = 'From: "Name Lastname" <myemail@mail.com>' . "\r\n" . 
          'Reply-To: "Name Lastname" <myemail@mail.com>' . "\r\n" .
          'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        #set autoresponders based on dropdown choice            
        switch( $posted_data['states'] ){
            case 'California':
            $msg="California email body goes here";
            break;

            case 'Texas':
            $msg="Texas email body goes here";
            break;

        }

        #mail it to them
        mail( $posted_data['email'], 'Thanks for your enquiry', $msg, $headers);
    }
}
```

What's wrong!?

Comment: I've always used only `\n` in emails, never `\r\n`. Is that possibly what's breaking your headers? Maybe it's being read as two line breaks?

Comment: It's also possible that, since changing the "From," you're breaking some mail delivery rules that cause it to go into spam or even be blacklisted. Try setting the "From" to an email address that ends in the domain of the website you're actually sending the email from.